# Mongo DB remote access on Windows server

Tags: database, mongodb, remote-access

How do I enable remote access to my mongo db server running on my own personal windows machine? I’ve read that I need to bind my IP address to 0.0.0.0 in a config file. I found some instructions online for Linux. But I am running a windows server. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you think it would be different on Windows?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't. But I googled this question and only found Ubuntu solutions. I am not sure how to transcribe those instructions into cmd commands.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I was trying to follow this, but got stuck on opening up the network port step: https://medium.com/founding-ithaka/setting-up-and-connecting-to-a-remote-mongodb-database-5df754a4da89

Comment: Config files are the same on any operating system. There are a few differences but they are clearly documented. So, simply configure it as given in your question (or read the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/))

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit What is the windows equivalent of this? sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring but this would be different to your question

Comment: Your question lacks many details. Binding to `0.0.0.0` means bind/listen on all network interfaces. By itself, that will not allow public access. Does your Windows machine have a public IP address assigned to it? If not, you must use a NAT configuration to route traffic from your public router to your Windows machine. How depends on your ISP, gateway, network configuration, etc.